# How to correctly graph data in Python

Tags: python, csv, matplotlib, graph

I have been trying to create a python script that can read the csv files I have converted and graph the density column. The issue is that the graph is outputting:
[image: MatPlotLib Graph]

Instead of:

[image: Excel Graph]

which is gotten through Excel.

A snippet of the data I used is here:

```
time,sza,alt,lat,lon,x,rho,hperiod,hperiodquality,vperiod,vperiod delaytime,vperiodquality,cutoff,ionospheretrace delaytime,maxfreqquality,groundtrace delatytime,density
2015-08-20 11:24:12.292,111.07 deg,1208 km,-73.42 deg,234.34 deg,-0.49 Rm,1.26 Rm,0,0,1.588E00,167.443 μs,1,0,167.443 μs,0,167.443 μs,0.0
2015-08-20 11:24:19.836,110.86 deg,1198 km,-73.74 deg,234.15 deg,-0.48 Rm,1.26 Rm,0,0,0,167.443 μs,0,0,167.443 μs,0,167.443 μs,0.0
2015-08-20 11:24:27.379,110.64 deg,1188 km,-74.06 deg,233.96 deg,-0.48 Rm,1.26 Rm,0,0,1.621E00,167.443 μs,2,0,167.443 μs,0,167.443 μs,0.0
2015-08-20 11:24:34.922,110.43 deg,1177 km,-74.38 deg,233.75 deg,-0.47 Rm,1.26 Rm,4.131E-02,1,1.654E00,167.443 μs,1,0,167.443 μs,0,167.443 μs,21.162049047375756
2015-08-20 11:24:42.465,110.22 deg,1167 km,-74.70 deg,233.53 deg,-0.46 Rm,1.26 Rm,4.205E-02,2,1.641E00,167.443 μs,1,0,167.443 μs,0,167.443 μs,21.927005570408877
2015-08-20 11:24:50.008,110.00 deg,1157 km,-75.02 deg,233.30 deg,-0.46 Rm,1.25 Rm,4.285E-02,2,1.654E00,167.443 μs,1,0,167.443 μs,0,167.443 μs,22.769263297305073
2015-08-20 11:24:57.552,109.78 deg,1147 km,-75.34 deg,233.06 deg,-0.45 Rm,1.25 Rm,4.223E-02,2,1.579E00,167.443 μs,2,0,167.443 μs,0,167.443 μs,22.115129637253784
2015-08-20 11:25:05.095,109.57 deg,1137 km,-75.67 deg,232.80 deg,-0.45 Rm,1.25 Rm,4.434E-02,2,1.579E00,167.443 μs,2,0,167.443 μs,0,167.443 μs,24.38028085178149
```

While I know the graph from Python will not be identical, the shape that MatplotLab is giving me isn't even close.

This is the code that I have been using:

```py
import os
import csv
import glob
from csv import reader
from matplotlib import pyplot
import numpy as np


for file in glob.glob("*.csv"):
    f = open(file, 'r')
    print(file)
    data = list(reader(f))
    density  = [i[16] for i in data[1::]]

    pyplot.plot(range(len(density)),density)
    pyplot.yscale('log')
    axes = pyplot.gca()
    axes.set_ylim([0,10**4])
    pyplot.locator_params(axis='x', nbins=10)
    pyplot.title('Density change over time')
    pyplot.xlabel('Number')
    pyplot.ylabel('Density')
    pyplot.savefig('Graphs/' + os.path.splitext(file)[0] + '.png')
    pyplot.cla()
```

in which my csv has the density in the 17th column. When printing out the density list, it even gives it to me as the correct values, in their correct order.

I have no clue what is happening here, and if someone would be able to help me out, that would be amazing.

Thank you everyone!

Comment: You will have to provide the actual data to us so that we can reproduce the problem and try to provide an answer. Since you seem to be new to Stack Overflow, you should read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was fixed by instead just logging the data before plotting, instead of using a log graph. I also made the density into a numpy array:

```py
    data = np.genfromtxt(file, delimiter=',')
    density  = data[:,16].flatten()
    density = np.log(density)
```